Place pixels on a grid
I have a two dimensional numpy array: myarray=[[0,0],[1,1],[2,2]]
I also have a grid of points: mygrid=[[70,70],[100,100],[30,30]]
I want to efficiently create a new array which contains points of myarrray added to the grid:
desired_result=[[70,70],[71,71],[72,72],[100,100],[101,101],[102,102],[30,30],[31,31],[32,32]]

One can imagine placing a 1x3 pixel block on the positions of the grid. If I work with a matrix which consists of np.ones(dimensions), swapping the ones for zeros at place of the desired_result creates a grid of 1x3 pixel blocks.
One can use coordinates that describe a circle/geometrical shape at the place of myarray, which would then create a grid of circles/geometrical shapes.

What is your programming question about this?

I don't understand what is the problem.

I must add that, like others, I don't see the relation between the preamble (the circle thing) and the question. I've answered anyway (even tho, usually, I don't answer to a question before it is fully clarified) because the only real question here is the one I've replied too (the rest are seemingly irrelevant and incomprehensible, tbh, elements of context). You should remove irrelevant elements of context, that is remove references to the circles.

Unless there is also a question about circles here? In which case, there would be 2 different questions (since the one I've replied to is independent). In that case, if you have 2 questions (one about circles, the other about adding points to grid), you should ask them in 2 separated posts (and clarify the question about circle, because it is really not clear. I can only surmise it is about "how to fill screen with circles whose centers are in map", but you haven't said it)

@chrslg I think that in the intended application myarray consists of points that form a circle and mygrid is the "black canvas" and the desired result is the grid of circles. I don't see any other way of making sense of the answer. Good answet, btw (+1)

@JohnColeman could be indeed. My hypothesis was that myarray was a list of centers (like "map" in the first part), and mygrid that circle example (the same as myarray in your hypothesis). So result=myarray[None,...]+mygrid[:,None,:] is a list of coordinates of all points of all circles whose centers is one of myarray. And then, the remaining stage would have been to use that as a index to "draw" on screen. screen[(xy[:,1], xy[:,0])]=0 for example.

I must say you guys are very smart to have it figured out with my question being phrased like that ahhahahahahaha

For the last part of the question the answer is straightforward. That is what broadcasting is for
myarray=[[0,0],[1,1],[2,2]] 
mygrid=[[70,70],[100,100],[30,30]]
result = (np.array(myarray)[None,:,:] + np.array(mygrid)[:,None,:]).reshape(-1,2)

Some explanations:
A=np.array(myarray)[None,:,:] is [[[0,0],[1,1],[2,2]]], that is a 3D array, whose first dimension has only 1 element (myarray itself). So a 1×3×2 array, such as A[0,i,j] = myarray[i,j]
B=np.array(mygrid)[:,None,:] is [[[70,70]],[[100,100]],[[30,30]]], so a 3D array, whose 2nd dimension has only 1 element each time. So a 3×1×2 array such as B[i,0,j] = mygrid[i,j].
And because of broadcasting, adding a size-1 array X to a size-n array Y adds the element on each of the n elements of Y (array([12]) + array([10,20,30]) is array([22,32,42])), and that for each axis, the result of A+B is a 3×3×2 array, whose element (A+B)[i,j,k] is A[0,j,k]+B[i,0,k] = myarray[j,k]+mygrid[i,k]. So what you want, or almost so.
You want to have those in sequence, that is a 9×2 array. Which is achieved by reshaping the result to a 9×2 shape (I've used a -1×2 shape, since I am allowed to replace one of the dimensions size by -1, which is then computed automatically. So, I was too lazy to compute the total size, len(mygrid)*len(myarray), and since 2 is a constant here, it was easy to rely on simply this -1.

yea I tried to frame the questions correctly and started with the full problem (which is about circles just as you assumed) but then I realized it would be simpler to just explain in the terms of pixels, which is what I then did and forgot to delete the first part. Im editing the question rn so it makes sense. Thank You for the great answer!
